# Merge ndarrays intro 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I have a `ndarray` can I merge them into a `1D` array?

Example:

```
v = [
  [1 2],
  [3 4]
]
```

into

```
v = [1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Check out [`flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Comment: @ksohan no, but flatten() did help.

Comment: @r.r., if an answer worked for you you should accept it, welcome back to SO anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
v = v.flatten()
```

Check also [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists), that is the same thing applied to Python's `list`s